# How to get specific SQL error code when executing Postgres query in php script

Tags: php, postgresql

How to get a specific SQL error code, for example "23505 unique_violation" in Postgres and php. I want to execute parametrized query or prepared query and get specific SQL error code returned by the query.

I don't want to use pg_last_error because if multiple queries cause errors the returned information may be unreliable. And I don't want to use pg_send_query because asynchronous execution does not work with my script.

Here is an example query for which I would like to receive a specific SQL error code.

```
$query =  '   select count(id) as users_count '.    
         '     from "users" '.
         '    where country = $1 ';                        
  $result = pg_query_params($db_connection, $query, array($country));
```

Comment: http://php.net/manual/en/function.pg-result-error.php

Comment: Thanks for comment however pg_result_error only works when sending queries asynchronously pg_send_query(). I need the SQLSTATE error from a synchronous query.